# How I have to validate the checkbox in customer account signup form?

Tags: forms, validation, magento

I am new to magento. How I have to validate the checkbox in customer account signup form?.

Which class is used to validate the checkbox in magento?

Comment: please specify if you like to validate it in frontend or backend or both and which part gives you the trouble here

Comment: In Frontend i have to validate a checkbox

Answer (score 8):

In frontend you can validate the checkboxes by adding them the class `"required-entry"`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="something" name="something" value="1" title="something" class="checkbox required-entry">
```

you can read more on this from http://blog.speedupmate.com/post/4062082985/javascript-validation-methods-in-magento